# Laravel Queue in Cron Cpanel

Tags: laravel, cron, queue, cpanel, laravel-7

I am having trouble running Laravel job queues from Cpanel shared server.

In the **app / Console / Kernel.php** add:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
     
        $schedule->command('queue:work --tries=3')
        ->cron('* * * * * ')
        ->withoutOverlapping();
    }
```

Somewhere I read that adding the following line in the index can cause problems with the queues

**Index.php**

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

The problem is that I tried countless commands and it doesn't work for me, the last one I added is:

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/brooklyn/Sistema/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2&1
```

I use Laravel 7, php version 7 and my shared server uses 7.2 and can be 7.4, I already tried these versions and none works for me.

I receive the following message in the mail sent from the server:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: 1: command not found
```

Please I will be extremely grateful to receive any suggestions that help me.

Comment: Are you able to run `/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php` command manually, in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a mistake in your cron command:

```
>> /dev/null 2&1
```

should be

```
>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Not that I already tried it. Now I actually have it as follows: /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/brooklyn/Sistema/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: In this way, the email configured in Cpanel does not reach me, do you know if the email only arrives when there is an error? or is it always sent?

Comment: Sorry, not using cPanel.

Comment: The cpanel has no command line. I really appreciate your good disposition. I'll keep looking.